# Data saving and accesing it from a different place

Tags: c#, python, database

I am working on a project that is storing float data that is scraped from different web sitest... The data is refreshed every minute (for later chart/graph display...) and now I would need to store each float with a timestamp with it... At this moment I have 5 different floats from 5 different web sites.

All this is being done on a Linux server with a Python script...

**Question 1:**

How should I design the layout of the data in the file it will be stored, so it will later be easily accessible?

Do I make my own layout? Something like this:

`[28.06.2017][data1=1234.12][data2=2345.23][data3=3456.34]...
...`
Or maybe I was thinking of using somethink like JSON? Will that work for a lot of data?

**Question 2:**

Now I would need ta make the data available so that I could open and read it from a different place (my computer running a C# application that is displaying charts/graphs). Do I need to make some sort of a database for this, or can I just open the files that are on the Linux server and how?

And of course everything would need to be refreshed every second/a few seconds...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Try xml which can be save to file and displayed in website.

Comment: You have many options, you could store it in a file `json`, or even `csv` would work well. You could could store it in a `SQL` or `NOSQL`database. What do you mean different place, different programs, different computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing a lot of data and then reading it simultaneously from multiple applications then you are probably better off using a database. Yes, you could do make it work in a file but imagine trying to read/write from a file simultaneously. Add to that, you want to plot the data into a chart and probably let the users select time range etc. Database queries will be your friend for these circumstances.

For the data schema, I'd consider multiple questions before you choose which kind of database(sql db vs nosql/document db).

- What sort of graph/chart you will be putting the data into. i.e will your reporting support minute by minute plotting?
- Will the number of data source change in time from 5 to 10 to 4 etc?

I'd look at PostgreSQL for this since it also [supports json as a datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html). With this route you dont have to worry much about varying data source.

Hope this helps you to think more on your problem + solution.

Comment: I tried PostgreSQL but I had some difficulties, I then installed MySQL and it is now working. You pointed me in the right direction. Thank you.